# PENTAHO ETL unable to insert more than 1100 records from one table to another

Tags: postgresql, etl, pentaho

hi all I have to work with Pentaho DT, it is a community version, so it doesn't have support.
My issue is that it doesn't insert  more than 1100 records

[image]

read from temp table step is reading data from the table (20 000 records) and passing it to the table output. Which is supposed to wright those records into DWH, however after it right 1100 records it's just sitting and doing nothing, locking the table in DWH where it was trying to do insert
[image]

[image]

Also, another question is there a way to force the step to wait for the previous step to be complete?
I have some steps which are supposed to create objects, and the next step is to assign an index, and sometimes if failed as the previous step is not finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in SQL statements which were locking table which was used to insert records, and because of transformation now I need to find out how to wait until all transformation steps are complete. and after that. execute another, but need to complete all previous[image]

how to force if to execute INDEXES and Clean up only after all previous steps are complete
[image]

this step fired as first previous step is complete

Comment: An INSERT doesn't lock the table in Postgres

Comment: To force the INDEXES AND CLEAN UP transformation to execute after the rest of the previous transformations are finished you have to put all the previous transformations in a separate job, so the transformation is launched when previous job has finished successfully.